# Returning information back from a JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JFrame` that has a `Panel` for `JButtons` to navigate between the two `JPanels` (`RegistrationPanel` and `ConfirmationPanel`). The two `JPanels` are switched between each other by using `CardPanel/CardLayout`. When the user enters information in the `RegistrationPanel` is there a way to get this information back to `StartFrame` listed below?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class StartFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    JButton previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
    JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
    JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();
    CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout(10, 10);

    public StartFrame()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        nextButton.addActionListener(this);
        previousButton.addActionListener(this);
        previousButton.setVisible(false);
        registerButton.addActionListener(this);
        registerButton.setVisible(false);

        Panel buttonsPanel = new Panel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        buttonsPanel.add(previousButton);
        buttonsPanel.add(nextButton);
        buttonsPanel.add(registerButton);

        setCardLayout();
        add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonsPanel);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, cardPanel);
    }

    private void setCardLayout()
    {       
        cardPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);
        cardPanel.add(new RegistrationPanel(), "registration");
        cardPanel.add(new ConfirmationPanel(), "confirmation");
        cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "registration");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getSource().equals(nextButton))
        {
            cardLayout.next(cardPanel);
            previousButton.setVisible(true);
            registerButton.setVisible(true);
            nextButton.setVisible(false);
        }

        else
        {
            cardLayout.previous(cardPanel);
            previousButton.setVisible(false);
            registerButton.setVisible(false);
            nextButton.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on who has the "active" role in passing this information. Should the RegistrationPanel pass the information back to the StartFrame (for example, when a button on the RegsitrationPanel is clicked?) Or should the StartFrame *fetch* information from the RegistrationPanel (for example, when a button on the StartFrame is clicked)?

In the first case, the RegistrationPanel needs a reference to the StartFrame (preferably in some more "abstract" form, to avoid the dependency to this concrete class). In the second case, the StartFrame needs a reference to the RegistrationPanel.

ROUGHLY sketched the approaches here:

For the first case:

```
class RegistrationPanel 
{
    private StartFrame startFrame;
    public RegistrationPanel(StartFrame startFrame) 
    {
        this.startFrame = startFrame;
    }

    // Called e.g. when a button was clicked on this panel
    void passBackInformationToStartFrame() 
    {
        startFrame.setInfo(this.getInfo());
    }
}


class StartFrame ...
{
    ...
    private void setCardLayout() 
    {       
        cardPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);

        // Remove: 
        //cardPanel.add(new RegistrationPanel(), "registration");

        // Add: 
        cardPanel.add(new RegistrationPanel(this), "registration");

        ....
    }
}
```

For the second case

```
public class StartFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    ...
    private RegistrationPanel registrationPanel

    private void setCardLayout()
    {       
        cardPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);

        // Remove: 
        //cardPanel.add(new RegistrationPanel(), "registration");

        // Add:
        registrationPanel = new RegistrationPanel();
        cardPanel.add(registrationPanel, "registration");
    }

    // Called e.g. when a button is clicked on this frame:
    void fetchInformationFromRegistrationPanel()
    {
        Info info = registrationPanel.getInfo();
        ...
    }
```